# How do I count or see unknown odd characters in a sequence?

Tags: grep, sequence

I have sequence data that I'm using for my Linux tutorials and I have to complete an activity like this. (Are there any sequences that contain non-nucleotides (something other than A, C, G, T or N)? I have to fish for characters different from the regular bases. I know the characters I'm looking for are there because I run a command to find an odd character 'n/N' and saw other odd characters.

```
grep -v $'sequence' filename.fasta |  grep -i $'n'
```

Output:

```
GAGGnCGATCCTGAACTCGTGGAGGAGCCAGTAGTGTGGC
PGQLMNARXNDSPGCGGCTTTTTGCCTCAGTGAATCTCTG
CGCTAGAATGCTTGTTAATNCCGTTTGCTGTAAACCTAAC
```

So I now I know there are other odd characters other than n/N, the problem is to figure our commands that will fish those odd ones (by odd I mean characters which are not A,T,G,C,N) in the sequence.

It's my first week with Linux, be kind.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I count or see unknown odd characters in a sequence?
> (by odd I mean characters which are not A,T,G,C,N)

To grep for these characters you can use a negated [character class](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html): `... | grep '[^ACGTN]'`

To see these characters colored you can use `... | grep --color '[^ACGTN]'`

To count the lines with such characters you can use `... | grep -c '[^ACGTN]'`

To count all these characters you can use `... | grep -o '[^ACGTN]' | wc -l`